# Determining if a knight can pass through all cells in a 2d array - if so print board

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, knights-tour

I need an advice regarding this problem called "Knight Path".
Given an n*n board whose cells are initialized to 0, I need to determine, given an arbitrary Knight's position, if the knight can pass through every cell on the board exactly once, where every cell the Knight had visited will be marked as counter, counting from: 1 - n^2.
If a path is possible, I need to print the board. I need to print all the valid boards.
The knight, for those who do not know the rules for chess, can move either up or down one square vertically and over two squares horizontally OR up or down two squares vertically and over one square horizontally.

For example given a 5*5 board, starting at (0,0) the method should print:

```
{{1,16,11,6,21},
{10,5,20,15,12},
{17,2,13,22,7},
{4,9,24,19,14},
{25,18,3,8,23}};
```

The above out put would be one of few, as there could be different other ways considering different initial positions.
I've written the below code but it doesn't print anything. I need to spot the logic flaws here so I can make it work.

```
public class KnightDemo {

    static int counter = 1;
    public static void KnightPath(int[][] b, int i, int j) {
        b[i][j] = counter;
        if (counter == b.length * b[0].length) {
            printMatrix(b);
            return;
        } else {
            counter++;

            if (isValid(b, i - 1, j + 2) && b[i - 1][j + 2] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i - 1, j + 2);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i - 2, j + 1) && b[i - 1][j + 1] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i - 2, j + 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i - 1, j - 2) && b[i - 1][j - 2] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i - 1, j - 2);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i - 2, j - 1) && b[i - 2][j - 1] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i - 2, j - 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i + 2, j - 1) && b[i + 2][j - 1] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i + 2, j - 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i + 1, j - 2) && b[i + 1][j - 2] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i + 1, j - 2);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i + 1, j + 2) && b[i + 1][j + 2] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i + 1, j + 2);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            if (isValid(b, i + 2, j + 1) && b[i + 2][j + 1] == 0) {
                KnightPath(b, i + 2, j + 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] a, int i, int j) {
        if (i > a.length - 1 || i < 0 || j > a[0].length - 1 || j < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] b = new int[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                KnightPath(b, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int[] rows: matrix) {
            StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
            buff.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                int value = rows[i];
                buff.append(value);
                if (i < rows.length - 1) {
                    buff.append(", ");
                }
            }
            buff.append("]");
            System.out.println(buff.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

Comment: If the goal is to hit every cell once, I don't see why the starting position matters.   It would seem like the only thing you can vary is "n".

Comment: @MarkLavin because I need to print *all* the different boards given different initial positions.

Comment: Your problem is that the evaluation of the first nested `if/else` always evaluate to false. Either `isValid(b,i-1,j+2)` returns `false` or `b[i-1][j-2] == 0` returns false. Because the `else` returns `void`, none of the rest cases execute. I commented all the return statements, and the output still the same. All values inside the `b` array are filled with 1.

Comment: Basically, whatever `counter` value is passed from main, that's the value added to each index location in the 2D array.

Comment: @hfontanez how do i assign the counter value only to the current cell?

Comment: @oryan7 I don't fully understand the problem. But first, you need to accumulate your `counter` variable because in the program execution it is only incremented locally. So, when you this evaluation `counter == b.length * b[0].length`, its value is always 1.

Comment: If you allow me to edit your code, I can replace it with the one I am running so that you could take it from there.

Comment: @hfontanez go ahead. thank you

Comment: @oryan7 since `counter` is a global variable, you don't really need to pass (`newCounter`) it  as a variable. I just made that change for you as well.

Comment: @oryan7 Here's the summary of your issue: you are only visiting each index once. How did I determine this? If I take this line `b[i][j] = counter;` and I add the contents of that location to `counter` before replacing its value (`b[i][j] = counter + b[i][j];`), the value set will not change; meaning the previous value at that index location was zero. Also, if I don't increment counter and call `printMatrix(b)` at the end, the array will be filled with whatever value I started with. If counter initial value was 5, the array will be filled with that value.

Comment: Fantatic, it works. but it only prints 1 matrix, how to I get it to print all matrices, given different starting points? it should print 303-304 of them.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. I just fixed the obvious problem related to counter variable not updating.

Comment: @hfontanez  I understand your solution and where my mistake was. what I'm asking is, the new code only prints 1 array, 1 possible path. Is there a way to print *all* the arrays with all different paths?

Comment: @oryan7 wait... I think it is starting to sink in. Do you want to capture, for a given position `b[i][j]` all possible paths a knight can take? For instance, given starting position of `b[0][0]` (top-left corner) a knight can take two paths, ending in: {{1,2}, {2, 1}}. Therefore, you want to print out that matrix. Am I correct? If so, this code is all wrong.

Comment: Yes exactly. well I'd appreciate it if you can point me at some direction so I can start  working on this :)

Comment: @oryan7 I posted my solution. I hope it is accurate.

Comment: @oryan7 I have updated my answer with two versions, one that maps the cell counter from top-left to the set of destination cell coordinates, and one that maps the coordinates of the current cell to the set of coordinates of the destination cells. I am really curious if this is really what you wanted.

Comment: @hfontanez my friend, this is exactly what I needed. I appreciate your time and your effort, I'd vote it up but I'm quite new to the site so I can't :/  thank you very very much!

Comment: @oryan7 if the answer satisfies your needs, click the checkmark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer. I will appreciate it if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP's explanation in the comments section, the goal is to map out all possible paths a knight can take from a location on the board. Basically, given the knight's location `b[i][j]`, calculate all legal paths.

If a knight is at {0, 0}, the knight has only two legal paths that end in {1, 2} and {2, 1}. The idea here is to capture that in a map. Then, move on to the next location on the board (i.e. {1, 0}) and repeat the process. Since each board location can be identified as an integer (`counter`), we can use it to map the paths...

```
0=[{1, 2}, {2, 1}]
1=[{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}]
...
n=[{n^-2 - 3, n^-2 - 2}, {n^-2 - 2, n^-2 - 3}] // last location is always a corner
```

To make it simple, I decided to create a Java `record` of coordinates to store the {*x, y*} coordinates of the end location of a given path, making my map `<Integer, Set<Coordinates>>`

The logic here is quite simple. First, seed the map with empty lists for each one corresponding location in the matrix. Then, iterate through the matrix (2D array) and calculate all the legal paths a knight can take from this location. For each legal path, add the `Coordinates` of the end location of the path. I used a `Set` to eliminate duplicate coordinates.

My solution (perhaps not optimal) is as follows (used OP code as baseline) - Need Java 15 or later to run. For Java 14 or earlier, replace `Coordinates` with an `Integer[]` of length 2, and store the coordinates in it.

```
public class KnightDemo {

    static int counter = 0;
    static Map<Integer, Set<Coordinates>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void KnightPath(int[][] b, int i, int j) {
        Set<Coordinates> paths = map.get(counter);
        if (isValid(b, i - 1, j + 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i - 1, j + 2));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i - 2, j + 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i - 2, j + 1));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i - 1, j - 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i - 1, j - 2));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i - 2, j - 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i - 2, j - 1));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i + 2, j - 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i + 2, j - 1));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i + 1, j - 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i + 1, j - 2));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i + 1, j + 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i + 1, j + 2));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, i + 2, j + 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(i + 2, j + 1));
            map.put(counter, paths);
        }

        counter++;
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] a, int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && i < a.length && j >= 0 && j < a[0].length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] b = new int[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                map.put(counter, new HashSet<>()); // add a new set before calculating paths
                KnightPath(b, i, j);
            }
        }
        map.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static record Coordinates(int row, int col) {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + row + ", " + col + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

The program outputs:

```
0=[{1, 2}, {2, 1}]
1=[{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}]
2=[{2, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}]
3=[{2, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}]
4=[{2, 3}, {1, 2}]
5=[{2, 2}, {0, 2}, {3, 1}]
6=[{2, 3}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}, {3, 2}]
7=[{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {2, 4}, {0, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 0}]
8=[{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {3, 2}, {2, 1}]
9=[{3, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 2}]
10=[{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}]
11=[{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {0, 2}, {4, 0}, {4, 2}]
12=[{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}, {0, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 0}, {1, 0}, {4, 3}]
13=[{1, 1}, {4, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 4}, {4, 2}, {3, 1}]
14=[{1, 2}, {0, 3}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}]
15=[{2, 2}, {1, 1}, {4, 2}]
16=[{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 0}, {4, 3}]
17=[{1, 1}, {4, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {4, 0}, {2, 0}]
18=[{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 1}]
19=[{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {4, 2}]
20=[{3, 2}, {2, 1}]
21=[{3, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 0}]
22=[{3, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}]
23=[{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}]
24=[{2, 3}, {3, 2}]
```

### UPDATE: Can you use this in a real game of chess?

Yes, you can! Suppose you seed the matrix with `black` and `white`. You could enhance the logic so that, if the end location corresponds to your color, you don't add as a valid path since it is blocked by one of your pieces.

### SECOND UPDATE: Same code but using `Coordinate` object as key

```
public class KnightDemo {

    static int counter = 0;
    static Map<Coordinates, Set<Coordinates>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void KnightPath(int[][] b, Coordinates coordinates) {

        Set<Coordinates> paths = map.get(coordinates);
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() - 1, coordinates.col() + 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() - 1, coordinates.col() + 2));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() - 2, coordinates.col() + 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() - 2, coordinates.col() + 1));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() - 1, coordinates.col() - 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() - 1, coordinates.col() - 2));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() - 2, coordinates.col() - 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() - 2, coordinates.col() - 1));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() + 2, coordinates.col() - 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() + 2, coordinates.col() - 1));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() + 1, coordinates.col() - 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() + 1, coordinates.col() - 2));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() + 1, coordinates.col() + 2)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() + 1, coordinates.col() + 2));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
        if (isValid(b, coordinates.row() + 2, coordinates.col() + 1)) {
            paths.add(new Coordinates(coordinates.row() + 2, coordinates.col() + 1));
            map.put(coordinates, paths);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] a, int i, int j) {
        return i >= 0 && i < a.length && j >= 0 && j < a[0].length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] b = new int[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(i, j);
                map.put(coordinates, new HashSet<>());
                KnightPath(b, coordinates);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        map.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static record Coordinates(int row, int col) {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + row + ", " + col + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
{0, 0}=[{1, 2}, {2, 1}]
{2, 2}=[{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}, {0, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 0}, {1, 0}, {4, 3}]
{4, 4}=[{2, 3}, {3, 2}]
{0, 1}=[{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}]
{2, 3}=[{1, 1}, {4, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 4}, {4, 2}, {3, 1}]
{0, 2}=[{2, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}]
{2, 4}=[{1, 2}, {0, 3}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}]
{0, 3}=[{2, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}]
{0, 4}=[{2, 3}, {1, 2}]
{3, 0}=[{2, 2}, {1, 1}, {4, 2}]
{3, 1}=[{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 0}, {4, 3}]
{1, 0}=[{2, 2}, {0, 2}, {3, 1}]
{3, 2}=[{1, 1}, {4, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {4, 0}, {2, 0}]
{1, 1}=[{2, 3}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}, {3, 2}]
{3, 3}=[{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {4, 1}, {2, 1}]
{1, 2}=[{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {2, 4}, {0, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 0}]
{3, 4}=[{2, 2}, {1, 3}, {4, 2}]
{1, 3}=[{0, 1}, {3, 4}, {3, 2}, {2, 1}]
{1, 4}=[{3, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 2}]
{4, 0}=[{3, 2}, {2, 1}]
{4, 1}=[{3, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 0}]
{2, 0}=[{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}]
{4, 2}=[{3, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}]
{2, 1}=[{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {0, 2}, {4, 0}, {4, 2}]
{4, 3}=[{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}]
```

They don't print in the same order, but you can tell that coordinates `{2, 2}` is the same set as `counter==12` in the previous example. Cell {2, 2} is the 13th cell from the top-left.

Answer (score 0):

To solve for all paths, you need to reset the placed values of paths you've exhausted so that newer paths can access them.  Additionally, your counter should reflect how deep you've gone, so that if you back out to try another path, your counter should roll back, too.  I would recommend passing a counter as a parameter rather than using a static counter.  Also, if you want to try all valid possibilities, then you need to avoid those return statements whenever one possibility is deemed invalid.

```
public static void KnightPath(int[][] b, int i, int j, int counter) {
    ...
        if (isValid(b, i - 1, j + 2) && b[i - 1][j + 2] == 0) {
            KnightPath(b, i - 1, j + 2, counter+1);
        }
    ...
    b[i][j] = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
            KnightPath(b, i, j, 1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The OP posted: "_counting from: 1 - n^2. If a path is possible, I need to print the board. I need to print all the valid boards_" In the comments, OP confirmed that what he wants is to save all the possible paths and print them out. For example, for `b[0][0]`, you should save `[{1,2}, {2,1}]`.

Comment: @hfontanez He currently prints the board whenever it's completed in his call to printMatrix(b);

Comment: That doesn't work. I was the one who created that method because his previous version was working worse. But that implementation does not do what the OP wants. All the information is actually in the comments section under the question. He wants a mapping of all the destinations from an original square in the board. The output should be similar to the one I showed in my answer.  Go to the question and read the last 5 comments to get the full story.

Comment: It does exactly what he asks.  Instead of printing the first valid matrix it finds, it prints every valid matrix it finds.  The example output he provided already maps the paths 1..2..3.. and so on.